# whether the Gaussian elimination method could be used to solve for $p,q,r$?

Tags: gaussian-elimination

could anyone tell me whether the Gaussian elimination method could be used to solve for $p,q,r$?

$$2p+3q-r=3\\p-q+2r=-1\\
p+0\times q+3r=2$$

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Yes, you can use Gaussian Elimination.

Comment: Why are you doubtful?